# AngularJs + Bootstrap UI + Laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am having some difficulties on working with ui bootstrap as well as angularjs.

My own example disable the pagination, and i cant understand why as well as automatic update pagination after search text.
I have read some blogs that talk about versions errors between angularjs and ui botstrap.

For the example i use an array with clients but in the real app i have an http.get.
Here is my plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/lxiFdGkT5UZf2e4w20gw?p=preview

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have corrected the errors in this forked Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/ynOfcfuUoup4zUyDQ2YI?p=preview

It looks like you were using some of the attributes from the Bootstrap pagination instead of the Angular-Bootstrap one. I changed `current-page` to `page` and added `total-items` which is the size of your client array. I hope this helps.

Comment: it does solved disbaled problem, but know i ended up with other error, that is automatic update the pagination when searching something.

Comment: change `clients.length` to `filtered.length`. That seemed to work for me.